# Query to compress hourly data to on change

Tags: sql, compression

I am facing an issue where I have a table with millions of hourly records and need to create a query to compress the data on change.

Sample Data -

```
Start DateTime      End DateTime        Value

2015-09-13 6:00     2015-09-13 7:00     45

2015-09-13 7:00     2015-09-13 8:00     45

2015-09-13 8:00     2015-09-13 9:00     45

2015-09-13 9:00     2015-09-13 10:00    45

2015-09-13 10:00    2015-09-13 11:00    45

2015-09-13 11:00    2015-09-13 12:00    45

2015-09-13 12:00    2015-09-13 13:00    25

2015-09-13 13:00    2015-09-13 14:00    25

2015-09-13 14:00    2015-09-13 15:00    25

2015-09-13 15:00    2015-09-13 16:00    45

2015-09-13 16:00    2015-09-13 17:00    45

2015-09-13 17:00    2015-09-13 18:00    45

2015-09-13 18:00    2015-09-13 19:00    45
```

Expected Results -

```
Start DateTime      End DateTime        Value

2015-09-13 6:00     2015-09-13 12:00    45

2015-09-13 12:00    2015-09-13 15:00    25

2015-09-13 15:00    2015-09-13 19:00    45
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Ranking function may help you.

Assuming that `SampleData` -- is a table having those data,

This may be slow,

```
WITH HourlyData AS (
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY StartDate) AS RankId
    , StartDate, EndDate, Value
FROM SampleDate),

DateHourChanged AS (
SELECT DENSE_RANK () OVER  (ORDER BY (CASE WHEN A.Value <> B.value THEN 1 ELSE A.RankId  END)) AS ID
, A.StartDate, A.EndDate, A.Value
FROM HourlyData AS A
LEFT JOIN HourlyData AS B
ON A.RankId -1 = B.RankId
)

SELECT StartDate, EndDate, Value
FROM DateHourChanged
WHERE Id = 1
ORDER BY 1
```

I selected Previous and Current Hour, when value of the current hour differ from previous hour, then record the current hour.